# What is the sum of infinte values of x, where x tends to zero? Is the sum 0, or does it go on to become infinite?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, summation

I feel that the sum of all very small numbers should be ultimately infinite, however small they are. But I also feel that since all are tending to zero, even the sum will tend to zero? Which is right, if any?

Comment: Very small number is not a rigorous term.

Comment: You'll have to clarify your point, it's not very clear what you're asking. Are you discussing matters of converging series? Series like $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ or $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$? One does converge, the other doesn't for instance, although both terms you add tend to zero

Comment: No no, I meant Summation(x) from r=1 to r=infinity, where x tends to zero.

Comment: What does $x$ have to do with $r$?

Comment: @CameronBuie it means that I have taken x 'r' times, and 'r' is infinite. So basically I'm adding x to itself infinite times, when x is tending to 0. What's the value of this sum?

Comment: If $x$ is nonzero, then the sum is undefined, and since "tends to $0$" indicates being nonzero, then the sum's limit is still undefined. If $x$ *is* zero, then the sum is zero.

Comment: @CameronBuie,@Aman: Note that the typical definition of limits exclude infinity from being a possible limit, in which case we consider a statement that a limit is infinity to actually be syntactic sugar for a particular epsilon-delta definition. However, if you want to keep intuition you can work using the extended real line with both positive and negative infinity, in which case the infinite sum of a non-zero constant does exist and is either positive infinity or negative infinity.

Comment: @user21820: True (and +1 to your answer, for being the only one to truly address the OP's question so far).

Comment: @CameronBuie: Thanks! That's actually why I answered. =)

Answer (score 2):

Both your feeling are wrong: it's known for example that

$$1+\frac1{2^2}+\frac1{3^2}+\cdots+\frac1{n^2}+\cdots=\frac{\pi^2}{6}$$
so this sum is finite not equal to $0$.

Answer (score 1):

You have stumbled on a very large part of basic mathematical analysis: infinite series.

A lot can be said about them, but here is the run-down:

The sum of an infinite number of values is, generally, not defined. However, for a sequence of real numbers $a_1,a_2,\dots$, we can define a formal series

$$a_1+a_2+a_3+\dots = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n.$$

We say that this series is *convergent with a sum of $S$* if the sequence $a_1, a_1+a_2, a_1+a_2+a_3,...$, i.e. the sequence defined as $S_n = a_1 + a_2 + \dots + a_n$, is convergent with a limit of $S$.

---

It can be shown that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$, then the limit of $a_n$ must be $0$, but the converse is not true.For example, it is known that $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n$$ does not converge (if you sum enough elements, the number gets higher and higher). On the othe hand, the sum
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac 1 {2^n}$$ is convergent, summing to $1$.

Answer (score 1):

Note the following:

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x = \infty$ as $x\to 0^+$.

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x = -\infty$ as $x\to 0^-$.

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty x$ has no limit as $x\to 0$.

$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \lim_{x\to 0} x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty 0 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean
$$\infty\lim_{n\to0^+}n$$
it is undefined. But, if you mean
$$\lim_{n\to0^+}{\dfrac1nn}$$
then it is equal to $1$.